# React: Array of refs or array in ref.current

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to wrap my head around refs when working with many elements. Currently there is two ways to store multiple refs.

Array of refs

```
[useRef(null), useRef(null), ...]
```

Or an array in ref.current

```
useRef([])
```

I've read the docs but havent found anything on this topic. Both works but which one should you use? Maybe the latter option is better because the general rule is to not overuse refs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My way of handling many refs, for your reference:

```js
const self = useRef({}).current
const saveRef = key => r => { self[key] = r }

return (
  <div ref={saveRef("container")}>
    <input ref={saveRef("input")} />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats basically what I am doing right now. Declare an empty useRef and use callback refs to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, I don't think there is a definitive answer on this.  A ref stores a reference to a mutable value, so I guess it depends on what you consider the mutable value to be.  If you are mutating the array, then it makes sense to store the array in the useRef.  If you are mutating a list of values, it may make more sense to create a ref per value.  However, I think it is really just personal preference.

A word of caution; updates to the mutable value in a ref don't force a re-render.  I assume you are aware of this, as you've clearly read [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) recently, but thought I would just call it out.

EDIT:  Also, as you said, you shouldn't overuse refs, and if you need a whole bunch of them you may want to consider refactoring to reduce the number of refs per component.  I'd be very interested in your use case that requires so many refs.

Comment: Hey. I am trying to show the active menu item based on scroll position. As far as I am aware React doesn't expose such things (eg. positioning) so thats why I am forced to use refs.